# Laravel cannot install with composer. Any advice

Tags: laravel

I have followed tutorials on youtube.

I have installed composer

[image]

And follow the steps in the documentation

[image]

However, I run into a lot of Yellow Messages in the Command Prompt

[image]

And eventually, the installation just failed. And I have no idea what is happening.

Any advice?

Comment: Check your internet connection, it is unable to download packages.

Comment: As @CodyBrew said, it's unable to download packages. If you have proper internet connection, then it's possible that composer is not installed properly. Try installing Composer with the right instructions.

Comment: I did re-install composer again. but still have a lot of yellow messages

Comment: the laravel installation is taking a long time. and I need to wait for the installation. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: @AliJouadi No, composer is properly installed according to me he has also attached the screenshot of the composer.

Comment: Yes. Finally finished the installation. Nothing wrong with the steps. Just poor internet connection